# styling rails text type attribute

Tags: css, sql, ruby-on-rails

Probably had been asked before, so apologies in advance if I've missed it in my search.

How do I style a textbox of `text` type in the database such as my `content` attribute below?

```
= simple_form_for @article do |f|
.content-area
    = f.input :content, placeholder: "Write an Article...", label: false, class: "content-box"
    = f.submit 'Publish', class: "button"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to specify HTML-specific attributes, wrap them in `input_html` hash:

`= f.input :content, placeholder: "Write an Article...", label: false, input_html: { class: "content-box" }`

Also, your `.content-area` wrapper appears to be unindented (at least in this post, maybe your initial code is correct)

Comment: I can successfully set the width of the box but not the length, plus the browser lets the user change the size of the box--how do I set it to be fixed?

Comment: Use html `rows` attribute. As for being able to resize the input, add `resize: none` for it to your CSS.

Comment: Thank you. Another thing i've noticed is that in Firefox the font (only inside the textbook) and border properties change--is there a way to fix this?

Comment: To address that, you'll have to style these properties yourself.